# How can I parse a Google Search by Image result?

Tags: html, parsing

I am trying to parse a Google Search by Image result with Unity.

For example, when I put an image of apple(fruit apple) as an input,
the result page will be shown and 'Searches closest to the image : apple'
will appear.

I need that 'apple' word which represents the image.

So I tried to parse it with HtmlAgiltyPack, but an error occurs and it says NullReferenceException, which means the node containing inner text of 'apple' can't be found.

The word 'apple' which I want to parse has a tag 'a' and attribute 'class=_gUb',
so I wrote the code like below:

```
foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@class='_gUb']"))
{
    string text = link.InnerText;
    Debug.Log(text);
}
```

At first time, I thought the error occurs because of my wrong source or poor HTML parsing skills,
but soon I realized that it was not code error when I succeeded in similar thing with other portal site(http://www.naver.com), though it was just a Search by Word result. But even if I tried to parse Search by Word result in Google, the same error occurs.

Could you please tell me the solution?
I already have searched about Google Custom Search API but it doesn't provide Search by Image API.

Comment: Are you sure (I'm just asking) text is there when you load page and it's not injected later with ajax?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking because I don't know about ajax. The thing only I know is that if I input an ordinary image, then there are "Searches closest to the image : 'something'" in result page, and that 'something' has a HTML tag.